# How to iterate through a list in a Go template

Tags: go

I have a function that retrieves a bunch of Tweets (of type Tweet) from a database and passes them to a template. In the template, I have to loop through the array and print the `message` field for each tweet retrieved from the db. The template below doesn't display anything at all.

How do I indicate that I'm looping through an array of type Tweet and then print the message for each?

```
    func Root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      tweets := []*Tweet{}
      t := template.Must(template.New("main").ParseFiles("main.html"))

      err := Orm.Find(&tweets)
      if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
        return
      }
      t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "main.html", tweets)
    }
```

main.html

```
 {{range .Tweet}}  
      status: {{.message}}
 {{end}}
```

Comment: You need to use `.Tweet.Message`, making sure that Message is exported (capitalised). You can also use `{{ with .Tweet }}{{ range . }}` to get the behaviour in your post: http://jan.newmarch.name/go/template/chapter-template.html

Comment: @elithrar the examples at the blog all refer to one struct and fields in the struct. However, I'm passing an array (or splice) to the template with numerous structs in it.  I can't get it to work using the blog example you referred to. Also, I'm not sure where you're suggesting I put `.Tweet.Message` Is that in the `{{ range }}` or when I'm actually trying to output the value? Either way, I can't get it to work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two errors here.

1. Where does `.Tweet` come from? You gave the template engine tweets, a []*Tweet as the input so `.` is a slice and has no `Tweet` field or key.
2. `.message` is not exported, only exported fields may be used in a template.

---

The end result:

```
{{range .}}
    status: {{.Message}}
{{end}}
```

Remember to modify your Tweet type to use the new field name.